# Request http with NSMutableURLRequest / URLRequest

Tags: ios, json, swift

What is the correct way to make a request to an api-rest?

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "https://myhost.com/test/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token")
var request =  URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
```

o

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://myhost.com/test/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token")! as URL,
                                  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)
```

When should I use one or the other?

Comment: You should always use Swift native types in this case `URL` and  `URLRequest`. You should always drop the `NS` prefix where possible. For mutable requests just declare it as `var` as you are already doing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Leo's comments,
Please find the sample classes for Request and Response below, which i use for making rest api calls.

Request class:

```
public struct APIRequest {

    let url: URL
    let method: HTTPMethod
    var httpHeaders: HTTPHeaders
    let body: Data?

    init(url: URL,
         method: HTTPMethod,
         httpHeaders: HTTPHeaders,
         body: Data? = nil
        ) {
        self.url = url
        self.method = method
        self.httpHeaders = httpHeaders
        self.body = body
    }
}

extension APIRequest {

    public func asURLRequest() -> URLRequest {

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: self.url)
        for (headerField, headerValue) in self.httpHeaders {
            urlRequest.addValue(headerValue, forHTTPHeaderField: headerField.rawValue)
        }

        urlRequest.httpMethod = self.method.rawValue
        urlRequest.httpBody = self.body
        return urlRequest
    }
}

extension URLRequest {

    public var debugDescription: String {

        let urlString = "URL: \(self.url?.absoluteString ?? "")"
        let methodString = "Method: \(self.httpMethod ?? "")"
        var httpHeadersString = "Headers: \n"
        for (headerField, headerValue) in self.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:] {
            httpHeadersString = httpHeadersString.appending("\(headerField) : \(headerValue) \n")
        }

        // Print Body as JSON

        let description = [
                urlString,
                methodString,
                httpHeadersString
        ]
        return "Request: { " + description.joined(separator: "\n") + " }"
    }
}
```

Response Class

```
public struct APIResponse {

    let request: URLRequest?
    let response: HTTPURLResponse?
    var jsonData: JSONObject?
    var data: Data?
    var statusCode: Int
    var url: URL?
    var httpHeaders: [AnyHashable: Any]?
    var error: Error?

    init(request: URLRequest?,
         response: HTTPURLResponse?,
         responseData: Data?,
         error: Error?) {
        self.request = request
        self.response = response
        self.jsonData = nil
        self.data = nil
        self.statusCode = 0
        self.url = nil
        self.httpHeaders = nil

        if let httpResponse = response {
            statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            url = httpResponse.url
            httpHeaders = httpResponse.allHeaderFields
            data = responseData
        }

        if statusCode == 401 {
            self.error = // Auth Error
        } else if (200..<300).contains(statusCode) == false {
            self.error = // Bad Error
        }
    }
}
```

HttpMethod

```
public enum HTTPMethod: String {

    case get = "GET"
    case post = "POST"
    case put = "PUT"
    case delete = "DELETE"
}
```

HttpHeaders

```
public typealias HTTPHeaders = [HttpHeadersKey: String]

public enum HttpHeadersKey: String {

    case contentType = "Content-Type"
    case userAgent = "User-Agent"
    case accept = "Accept"
    case date = "Date"
    case authorization = "Authorization"
}

public enum MIMEType: String {

    case json = "application/json"
    case imagePng = "image/png"
}

public struct DefaultHeader {

    var value = HTTPHeaders()

    init() {
        self.value[HttpHeadersKey.contentType] = MIMEType.json.rawValue
        self.value[HttpHeadersKey.accept] = MIMEType.json.rawValue
        self.value[HttpHeadersKey.date] = Date().rfc1123String()
    }
}
```